# Past participle vs being+past participle

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, past-participles

What is the difference in the meaning between the following sentences:

1. > Being beaten by snow, he died.
2. > Beaten by snow, he died.

Or:

1. > Being taken to the hospital, he survived.
2. > Taken to the hospital, he survived.

Here are my opinions about them:

When we use Being+past participle as a participle clause, it refers to the reason for the action of the main clause and it replaces 'Because'.

when we use past participle clause as a subordinate clause it also refers to the reason for the action in the main clause. Thus, both(being+p.p and p.p) work the same and their meanings also same in sentences. They convey the same meangs but only their construction is different. I'm not sure,so I'm confused here.

If i understand the usage and meaning of them, my confusion will certainly be eliminated.

Comment: What does the English verb **to be** mean? What form of that verb is the word _Being?_

Comment: P.E Dent'being' is present participle of verb 'be'

Comment: But what does "to be" mean in English? Once you grasp that, you will answer this question yourself. You know what the verb _eat_ means, and you know what _eating_ is. _Be_ and _being_ have the same relationship to each other.

Comment: @PE Dent I don't know its exact meanings all i think is 'be' is infinitive without to, being is present participle and been is past participle

Comment: *Be* doesn't mean anything most of the time. Most of the time it's used for grammatical reasons.

Comment: @snailplane The verb "to be" is at the heart of all Indo-European languages (and is also very important in the sense and structure of Semitic languages.) Without knowing what it means, it's not possible to really understand a phrase like "Being taken." I think it short-changes a learner to present **be** as a merely utilitarian utterance which links or assists verbs that "mean something." "Be" and its meaning are even important to the word the OP posits as being replaced by these participle phrases: "be/by cause."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

The two participle clauses you cite are in the *passive voice,* and *being*  puts them in the *present continuous* tense. They are *continuous passive participle* clauses.

Compare:

> *Continuous passive:*
>   Being beaten by (the*) snow, he died.<sup>†</sup>
>
> *Passive:*
>   Beaten by (the) snow, he died.
>
> *Active:*
>   The snow beat him, (and) he died.

One of your opinions about the two sentences is correct: *being+past participle* is identical in meaning to the *past participle* alone, and the gerund *being* can be omitted in both sentences.

*Being beaten* here is a *continuous passive participle.* Without *being,* it is a *passive participle.* Their meanings are nearly identical, and *being* can be omitted, but as you suggest, *being* in the first example emphasizes that he died *because* the snow beat him. It "tells a story", in a way, of the beating as it progresses. (In the longer and "optional" part of this answer, *because* is discussed more thoroughly.)

The verb **to be** is not just a useful and meaningless sound used to form tenses and the passive voice. *Be* is a "real" verb with a "real" meaning of its own. *Being* means *having place in the objective universe or realm of fact; existing.* In your sentence, *Being beaten* means *Existing in the state of "beaten"-ness.* Understanding what *being* really means, and thinking deeply about the verb **be** in relation to your two sentences, may open up for you an understanding of how the passive voice works in English, and the other ways in which we use the verb.

---

### Optional

The verb *to be* is often taught as a [*linking verb*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb) or [*auxiliary verb,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) and it performs those duties very well. However, without knowing what the verb *means,* it is impossible to truly grasp the sense of many constructions in English which employ **be** in its various forms—including, I think, its workmanlike service in linking and forming tenses and the passive voice.

In your first example, the verb **to be** helps to describe the cause of the subject's death:

> *Being* beaten by the snow, he died.

*Being beaten* is routinely analyzed as a *continuous passive participle* using the gerund of the verb *to be,* but with the "meat" of meaning provided by the participle *beaten.* Analysis might center on that verb's meaning; but the verb **be** is important here, even though it could be omitted without changing the sense of the sentence:

> Beaten by the snow, he died.

#### What does it mean to "be"?

In most beginning English classes, the verb *to be* is the first one studied. Because it is the most irregular of verbs, and because of its wide use as a linking verb, the forms of the [*copula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_copula) (as it is known to linguists) are memorized early on.

Webster's Unabridged Dictionary (1913) has this to say about *to be:*

1. To exist actually, or in the world of fact; to have existence.
2. To exist in a certain manner or relation, -- whether as a reality or as a product of thought; to exist as the subject of a certain predicate, that is, as having a certain attribute, or as belonging to a certain sort, or as identical with what is specified, -- a word or words for the predicate being annexed; as, to be happy; to be here; to be large, or strong; to be an animal; to be a hero; to be a nonentity; three and two are five; annihilation is the cessation of existence; that is the man.
3. To take place; to happen; as, the meeting was on Thursday.
4. To signify; to represent or symbolize; to answer to.

Many words are used to define this very small one, and rightly so. It is a part of the very "framework" of English (and of all Indo-European languages) and is so entwined in our languages that it has even "disappeared" in some of them: it is "understood" rather than spoken! After all, what is more elementary to language than the expression of *existence itself?* That is exactly what *to be* means.

When we say that something **is,** we are expressing its existence. When we say that something **was,** we express its existence in the past. The participle phrase *Being beaten* uses **be** in the sense of the second definition above: it expresses the state of existing *with the attribute of "beaten-ness."*

In comments, you were asked to compare the verb **to eat** and its participle **eating** with the verb **to be** and its participle **being.** Of course anyone knows what it means to eat; and anyone knows what the *act* of *eating* is. No matter what language they speak, all humans engage in *eating.* The same is true of *being,* and the definition of that word is easy to grasp if you consider that:

> **Being** is to *be* as **Eating** is to *eat.*

Of course, *eat* is a *dynamic verb* that describes an action, and *be* is a *stative verb* that describes a state or condition, but it is easy to understand that *being* and *eating* both express what happens when the action or state described by the verb is undertaken or experienced.

Here we can come back to the part of your question in which you suggest that the participle phrase *Being beaten* replaces the adverb *because.* You are nearly correct! It is *Being* which could be replaced, and we can express the same thought like this:

> *Because (he was)* beaten by the snow, he died.

Yet even here, the verb *to be* is involved: The adverb *because* is itself descended from the verb **be** and the noun **cause**! As Webster's 1913 Unbridged also tells us in its definition of *be:*

- Note: It is joined with certain substantives, and a few adjectives, to form verbs; as, bedew, befriend, benight, besot; belate (to make late); belittle (to make little). It also occurs in certain nouns, adverbs, and prepositions, often with something of the force of the preposition *by*, or *about*; as, belief (believe), behalf, bequest (bequeath); **because,** before, beneath, beside, between. In some words the original force of *be* is obscured or lost; as, in become, begin, behave, behoove, belong.

In the original form of *because,* the words *be* and *cause* were separate:

> For be-cause þat I know þe sorw þat þay haue, ich am com doune to deliuer hem.

(From a sermon composed in the 1400s by an unknown writer and preserved in a manuscript at Worcester Cathedral.)

> & þer power was adraw be cause he made þe signe of þe cros...

(from a [*Middle English Treatise on the Ten Commandments*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nSdVAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%22Be%20cause%22%20middle%20english&source=bl&ots=CbMkTfg3EI&sig=Vv8uvHnpOsOcbjle9zRevsV5mXE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHpuSY087PAhWKVD4KHd06DSsQ6AEIUzAM#v=onepage&q=%22Be%20cause%22%20middle%20english&f=false))

And Geoffrey Chaucer in *The Merchant's Tale* writes:

> If Hys Squyors / whiche fat stoodon ther bisyde
>   Excused hym / by cause of his siknosse

A discussion of the verb *to be* cannot but end by noting that it is the subject of what some believe to be the most perfect poetry written in English. In 1600 CE, The Bard of Avon put these words in the mouth of Hamlet, the Prince of Denmark:

> ***To be, or not to be, that is the question:***

---

<sup><sup>†</sup>
Both of your example sentences numbered as 1.) contain clauses in different voices and tenses, which presents problems not addressed by your question. In English, they would at least be written to agree in tense, e.g.:

*Being beaten by snow, he dies.

Being taken to the hospital, he survives.*</sup>

<sup>* I have here added the definite article which the questioner omitted in his example.</sup>

Comment: @Mari-LouA An integer is just an integer. My concern and fervent hope is that the OP here learns about the verb _be,_ and that he (and any subsequent learner of English) does _not_ take away from this question the dictum that **_Be_ doesn't mean anything most of the time. Most of the time it's used for grammatical reasons.**

Comment: With all due respect, but the OP has not asked  about the meaning of "be", but the difference between *being beaten* and *beaten*.

Comment: His question presents two examples of participle clauses and says: _"My confusion is closely related to the use of 'being+past participle'=being beaten."_ An understanding of the _meaning_ of the word **being** is central to his question. The participle "singing" or "skinnydipping" can't be substituted. It's about _being,_ and a true grasp of its meaning will allow him to answer this and similar questions himself. In fact, once he understands _be_ and _being,_ such questions will no longer exist!

Comment: Hi everyone, please move extended discussion to chat :) Thank you!

Comment: @P.E Dent please go to http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32962406#32962406 I have recently put my openion there.just replace me.Thanks

Comment: Does SE award a badge for perseverance and patience? :) You've earned it tenfold!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Heh! no badge, and even worse, no less a luminary than John Lawler has stated in ELU: _To be_ **has** no meaning, since it's just part of the machinery of grammar."_ \*sigh\*

Comment: @P.E Dent Sorry, I happened to ask another question which has been now marked as duplicate of this one. What I didn't understand from you is you said
that first example sentence is in "continueous participle clause in passive voice". I don't understand what "continueous participle clause in passive voice" mean.

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

> Being beaten by snow, he died

The above has clearly been written by a non native speaker, a learner who is trying to come to grips with a fairly advanced grammatical structure. By itself, without any context, it doesn't make much sense. The clause *beaten by snow* is not idiomatic, it borders on the paradox. How can "snow" (the substance) beat (physically)  a person to death?

### It's in the passive voice

If I'm mistaken on the exact terminology, I apologise, but the following answer should illustrate what "being beaten by snow" actually means.

---

Imagine an evil monster made out of snow, called Snow.
Note the capital letter, this tells us that **Snow** is someone or something which is alive and has a name.

One day Jon and Snow meet and have a fight. Snow starts by throwing snowballs at Jon, but the monster also has the power to unleash a howling [blizzard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blizzard). Jon can't possibly survive against Snow, the snowballs come thick and fast, they thrash against his legs, chest, head; and in the blizzard, Jon cannot see Snow.

Exhausted, and defeated, Jon's body *beaten* black and blue by the sheer force of the snowballs, he collapses and dies.

In the OP's examples, the receiver of the action, he, is elided.

**[Passive Voice](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/passive)**

Simple past

> **Active**: Snow beat Jon, and he died. (Snow is the subject, Jon is the object)
>   **Passive**: Jon was beaten by Snow, he died. (The subject and the object have switched places) 
>   **Passive**: Beaten by Snow, he died

But we could rewrite it without mentioning the agent, Snow, within a story this would make sense.

> **Passive**: Beaten, defeated, and exhausted, he died.

Present Continuous

> **Active**: Snow **is** beating Jon, he **dies**
>   **Passive**: Jon is being beaten by Snow, he dies
>   **Passive** Being beaten by Snow, he dies.

Past Continuous

> **Active**: Snow **was** beating Jon, he **died**
>   **Passive**: Jon was being beaten by Snow, he died
>   **Passive**: Being beaten by Snow, he died

Basic Rules (English Grammar Online)

> When rewriting active sentences in passive voice, note the following:
>
> 1. the object of the active sentence becomes the subject of the passive sentence
> 2. the finite form of the verb is changed (to be + past participle)
> 3. the subject of the active sentence becomes the object of the passive sentence (or is dropped)

Comment: Mari, the sentences against which you wrote **'passive'** are actually in active voice. In those sentences the matrix clause (or if you prefer the *superordinate clause* or *main clause*) is in active voice. The Past-Participle clause (or *ed participle* clause) which functions as an adjunct here gives out a passive sense; that means the implied subject of these *subject-less past participle* clause in not the agent within that non-finite clause.

Comment: Sentences don't have voice, clauses do. To me, _Being beaten by snow_ is a clause in the passive voice. The _main_ clause, "he died," is in the active voice. So @Mari-LouA has only made a labelling error here. If you folks _really_ want to contend over an answer, mine should provide fertile ground!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Rather than accepting any downvotes, why not just relabel the appropriate _clauses_ as active and passive instead of the _sentences?_ Just my 2 quatloos...

Comment: "The Basic Rules" is an excerpt taken from a website, whose link is found in *Passive Voice* highlighted in bold. It is they who write "sentences". I didn't mention the term; however, "active sentences" sounds absolutely fine to me and I don't believe that is the sticking point.

Comment: @yubrajsharma did my answer show you how  'being+past participle' is constructed? Did my answer help you to  understand what "beaten by snow, he died" actually means?  And the reason why it is an odd, and weird sentence? The same can be said for **"Being taken to the hospital, he survived"**. The structure is confusing, because the meaning *is* confusing. No one writes like that. Don't invent sophisticated sentences before you have learnt how to swim, you'll only drown. First, learn the basic stuff.

Comment: Keep your writing simple, be patient, and read, and read as much as you can. Books and literature will help you understand how to manipulate the language at your command.

Comment: @Mari-LouA On voice and tense in clauses as opposed to sentences, consider the sentence: **"He died, and is buried here."** In what voice is the sentence? In what tense?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Isn't it past simple, and in the active voice. The PP (buried)  is like an adjective, isn't it? A bit like "the red paper is torn", so does *torn* refer to its physical appearance or to the action it was submitted to? I think there are arguments in favour of both. But I am the wrong person to ask, you need someone like deadrat, John Lawler, or Stoney B.

Comment: In that sentence, the first clause is in simple past and active voice, and the second in the simple present and the passive voice. This sentence is often used to demonstrate that a sentence cannot have _voice_ and _tense;_ only a clause can have these properties.

Comment: https://books.google.it/books?id=QD_pVOM4Q3cC&pg=PA252&lpg=PA252&dq=%22He+is+buried%22+tense&source=bl&ots=l-qI7EJRMm&sig=LOtIr8QxfgugKpBgnIkQ5u2LT-4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_vfyosOLPAhUM7RQKHe6PAvAQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22He%20is%20buried%22%20tense&f=false Nobody knows :)

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Active: *They buried him* Passive: *He was buried*, but in your example be is in the simple present he is buried, and that describes his present condition, so I think *buried* performs more like an adjective, "the buried body" = "the body is buried".