# Being taken and being beaten

Tags: passive-voice, present-participles, participle-clauses, dangling-participle

In the previous **[question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106047/past-participle-vs-beingpast-participle)**  I was told that these sentences are clumsy and their meanings are confusing:

- Being taken to the hospital, he survived.
- Being beaten by the snow, he died.

Can I convert these sentence into meaningfull sentences as follows:

> 1. Being taken to the hospital, he died.

(To mean: while he was being taken to the hospital, he died)

> 2. Being beaten by mother to her son, the father arrived.

(To mean: While the son was being beaten by his mother, the father arrived)

and,

Do I have to use "while" in front of "being+past participle in above sentences to imply those intended meanings?

Comment: I know 'being' can be used with adjective. For example:
>Being a student, she works hard.
But, the use of being with past participle is confusing to me. 'being taken to the hospital' is said to be "continueous present participle in passive" which i don't understand because 'being taken to the hospital' implies ''while he was being taken to the hospital"

Comment: Your second sentence is problematic IMHO. If you use passive voice, that "to her son"-part shouldn't be there and it sounds wrong to me. Aside from that, that sentence looks to be a typical error of dangling participles that we (learners) make every now and then.

Comment: @cardinal, as you said it's wrong to use 'to her son! how can I remove "to her son" without changing the meaning of sentence?

Comment: @cardinal please reply me

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the ell. Why do you think you should add that part? I do not see any problem with "Being beaten by his mother, he saw that his father park the car."

Comment: @cardinal what kind of meaning would it (the sentence you suggested) have ?

Comment: That means while he was being beaten by his mother he saw that his father finished parking the car.

Comment: @cardinal Then, I'm going to edit the question to include this sentence

Comment: @cardinal I'm expecting a good understandable answer for this question. The answer would be helpfull to all English Learner.

Comment: I see your point. I think you can ask your questions on the main chat-room, too. Give it a try.

Comment: @Cardinal yeah ! I have asked http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaken in your belief that starting a sentence with

> Being **past participle**

in isolation has an implication of

> While he was being ...

In all cases I can think of we would explicitly include the extra information

> While he was being taken to the hospital he died
>
> While he was being beaten by his mother his father arrived

When we start the sentence with Being we are using the adjectival form

> Being a doctor he was able to give medical assistance
>
> Being a lawyer he was familiar with the legal process

Your example of

> Being beaten by the snow, he died

is actually an example of the adjectival form of being. It is important to realise that **beaten** also may be a verb or an adjective. In this example we are using beaten as an adjective meaning defeated.

> having been defeated by the snow, he died.

is the interpretation of

> being beaten by the snow, he died.

You are thinking of this as if it were like your previous "mother" example, as if the snow were beating, that is hitting, a person.

> while he was being beaten by the snow, he died

which is not the correct interpretation.

Comment: I haven't understood last part of your answer