# Do these sentences give same meaning?

Tags: construction

Do the following (1) and (2)sentences have the same meaning ?

1. Being taken to the hospital, he died.
2. While being taken to the hospital, he died.

( Do both sentences mean: while he was being taken to the hospital, he died)?

Is it correct to use No1 and No2 sentence? What kind of sentence construction they have? I Was told by @P.E Dent in previous question [Past participle vs being+past participle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106047/past-participle-vs-beingpast-participle/106091?noredirect=1#comment213121_106091)
that first example sentence is in "continueous participle clause in passive voice". I don't understand what "continueous participle clause in passive voice" mean.

Comment: The meanings are not identical, but the difference is so small as to be not worth mentioning. The second is much more idiomatic. The problem with the first one is that the _Being_ clause is in the present tense, while the main clause is in the past tense. _While_ in the second sentence changes the temporal perspective, making _died_ in the main clause more obviously the result of the action in the first clause.

Comment: Sentence No. 2 is much, much better.

Comment: Do sentences "give" meaning, or "have" **the** same meaning....?

Comment: Mari-LouA "give" can't substitude the meaning of "have" ?

Comment: @P.E Dent I thin I should have asked thishttp://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106638/being-taken-and-being-beaten/106653#106653
 All I want to know is starting the sentence from "being+past participle" as I have shown in my examples too
I thought that starting sentence with" being+p.p" gives the meaning the past participle continueous in passive as said by "P.E Dent". But I don't know what "continueous present participle in passive voice means".
For example:

Comment: 1."Being taken to the hospital,he died."
Does it mean "while he was being taken to the hospital,he died"? Or do I have to add "while" in front of "being" in the sentence to get that meaning ?
If this(1) sentence doesn't give that meaning, is it worthless to start the sentence with" being+past participle" ?

Comment: Yubraj, Yes both of your sentences have identical meaning. But your sentence #2 is much more common, especially in daily conversational English. Though the first one is not incorrect, it's more common in fiction/literature. @Mari-LouA already commented that your second sentence is far better. I think it's in line with the data analysis Biber et al demonstrated in LGSWE.

Comment: @P.E Dent please don't mind, I have addresed your name in my question

Comment: @FumbleFinger It can't be duplicate of previous question. Previous question's answer don't answer what 'continues passive participle clause " is. In this question I'm asking different question, please read that again, Next, here i'm here also asking about the construction of those sentences.

Comment: @yubrajsharma Pleaae don't worry! It is not a breach of etiquette to cite a username in a question, or even to misspell it.

Comment: @Man_From_India If you can cite the language from the Longman's book, it might help our Yubraj here, who does not seem to be benefiting from my own efforts!

Comment: @yubraj sharma: Your question *title* asks whether including the word "while" affects the meaning, but in the actual *text* you seem to be asking what "continuous passive participle clause" means. I think both these points are fully covered by [P. E. Dant's answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/106123/126) to your earlier question but if there was anything you didn't understand, you should post a comment there asking for clarification.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Ok will do it later. But it's one or two lines as to what is more common and what is not. Will write an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

> While being taken to the hospital, he died.

You are explicitly saying that while he was en route to the hospital, he died.

> Being taken to the hospital, he died.

This is ambiguous, we can't tell when he died.  It almost sounds like you are saying he died because he was being taken to the hospital, which is weird and will cause your listener or reader to have questions.

The exception to the ambiguity is if your context is recounting a series of events in terse language, in that case, this may translate to the first sentence.  Otherwise you should include the *while* for clarity.

Comment: @Larence C All I want to know is starting the sentence from "being+past participle" as I have shown in my examples too
In previous question's answer "@P.E Den said that the first sentence is in "present continues participle in passive voice.But I don't know what "continueous present participle in passive voice means".And is it worthless or meaningless to start the sentence with' being+past participle' ?

Comment: previous question means this question http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106047/past-participle-vs-beingpast-participle/106091?noredirect=1#comment213121_106091

Comment: In this case, you want to include *while*, but it's not automatically wrong to begin a sentence with *being + past participle*.  In this one it mostly is wrong, though.

Comment: The 2nd example is ambiguous, I interpret it as he died some time after reaching hospital (if you meant the first case, you would have used that construction, so you must mean the opposite).

Comment: @Lawrenc c  If it's not to start sentence with being+p.p,Could you provide some meaningfull example sentence starting with "being+p.p" like my examples

Comment: @Lawrence c Thanks for your answer. But there is a question about 'construction' of those sentence' and 'continueous passive participle' which hasn't been addresed in your answer.