# Am I interpreting the difference correctly? "being + [past participle]" vs. "[past participle]" in context

Tags: past-participles, participles, present-participles

Consider these two self-made sentences below.

> 1. Being armed with previous experiences, I decided to check the map at every crossroad.
> 2. Armed with previous experiences, I decided to check the map at every crossroad.

### My interpretation

I think inserting "being" before the past participle just adds a sense of momentariness to the participle clause. I mean it gives a sense of being a continuous action at the moment. I am confused about the difference between the two :(

Would you tell me what is the difference?

---

I've also checked the Q&A [Past participle vs being+past participle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106047/past-participle-vs-beingpast-participle), but I cannot come up with a solid answer about my question after reading the long answer there.

Comment: The issue is equipped with experience. The better word here is: armed with experience....

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pas participle."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is equipped with experience. The better word here is: armed with experience. Also: at every crossroad.

Armed with experience, I [whatever].

Being armed with experience, I [whatever].

Both are fine. Both imply: As I was armed with experience, I [whatever].

You don't really need the being.

Also, check the map "at the crossroads" does imply stopping at crossroads to check it.

Comment: I fixed those issues about "on" and "arm". Would you tell me if there's any difference between using "being + past participle" and just using "past participle" in such sentences?

Comment: If there were a difference, I would have said it.